# imageView.getWidth(); returns screen instead of bitmap width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an imageview that looks like this

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:onClick="Time"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

I'm trying to get the width of the image displayed in the imageview by using

```
ImageView artCover = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
int coverWidth = artCover.getWidth();
```

But the width returned is the same as the screen width and not of the image (when the image width is less then the screen width). If I do

```
int coverHeight = artCover.getHeight();
```

I get the correct height of the image. How can I get the width of the displayed image?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your imageview's bitmap is probably scaled and aligned accordingly. You need to take this into account.

```
// Get rectangle of the bitmap (drawable) drawn in the imageView.
RectF bitmapRect = new RectF();
bitmapRect.right = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
bitmapRect.bottom = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

// Translate and scale the bitmapRect according to the imageview's scale-type, etc. 
Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
m.mapRect(bitmapRect);

// Get the width of the image as shown on the screen:
int width = bitmapRect.width();
```

(note that I haven't tried to compile above code, but you'll get the gist of it :-)).
The above code only works when the ImageView has completed its layout.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising, but is there any way to do this on API 9 (getMatrix requires API 11)?

Comment: I made a typo: The call should be getImageMatrix(), not getMatrix. And getImageMatrix is available for api9.

Comment: That works! I just had to convert the float from bitmapRect.width to an integer. Huge thanks, I've been struggling with this for some time now ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait till the View tree has been measured completely which might be even later than onPostResume(). One way to deal with that is:

```
final ImageView artCover = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
artCover.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int coverWidth = artCover.getWidth();
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Tried this but it doesn't work. The getWidth(); is called on an onClick event, much later than the onPostResume() so I don't think that's the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

You can get image from imageview and will get width the image.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)artCover.getDrawable()).getBitmap();<p>
bitmap.getWidth();
```

Comment: Thanks. This gets me the original bitmap's width, but not the scaled bitmap's width.